# GPU running out of memory, just by importing BERT pretrained Model

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model

So I was trying to figure out why my Model won't run and which part of it takes up all of the GPU memory since I always got the same error: `RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 120.00 MiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 4.85 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 4.89 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF`

I was googling it and everybody was saying that maybe the tensors I'm saving are too big but that wasn't the case, they took up no memory at all when saving them.

So I started to use `torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated()` to find out which part takes up all the memory and found out that when I use my `model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", num_labels=len(codes)) model.cuda()` the memory I have is already nearly filled fully and the model can't run.

I am pretty new to this field so I am using a pretrained model but with no success yet. I hope anybody already had the same error and knows how to fix it. Thanks in advance

Comment: BERT is a big model. After model.cuda() the parameters are stored in the VRAM and you seem to have almost not enough memory to store all of them. Then when you run it you store the data and calculation in the VRAM as well and therefore you come in OOM. So the solution is to run on CPU or try a smaller transfo (reduce the max seq len, the latent space size or the number of block)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I will it out without using my GPU and see what happens.